# Compare dates, prices, names and categories and print most profitable name

Tags: python, file

I'm making program that print most profitable element for every category from file in range of dates.

```
date_cat_profit_dict = {}

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        date, category, name, profit = line.split("|")
        profit = int(profit)

        composite_key = "{0}|{1}".format(date, category)

        _, max_profit = (date_cat_profit_dict.setdefault(composite_key, ("", 0)))

        if max_profit < profit:
            date_cat_profit_dict[composite_key] = (name, profit)

for composite_key, (name, profit) in date_cat_profit_dict.items():
    print("{0} --> {1}".format(composite_key, name))
```

*File example:*

```
05/01/2016|category6|Name8|4200
06/01/2016|category1|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category3|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category1|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category3|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category2|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
08/01/2016|category2|Name1|1000
09/01/2016|category4|Name7|3100
```

Dates will be always on asending order.

***Problem:***

I have to implement user entries of range o dates. This program will print all from files. Also i have two different names for one category.

***Example for this program.***

```
07/01/2016|category2 --> Name2
09/01/2016|category4 --> Name7
07/01/2016|category3 --> Name2
07/01/2016|category1 --> Name2
08/01/2016|category2 --> Name1
06/01/2016|category1 --> Name1
05/01/2016|category6 --> Name8
```

***My excepted result:***

*when program start it ask me for start date and end date and after this it will print most profitable element for every category.*

**input:**

Start: 07/01/2016

End:08/01/2016

**output:**

Category1 : Name2

Category2 : Name2

Category3 : Name3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing detailed code, I prefer to provide you missing pieces.

Datetime comparison tool

```
>>> import time
>>> date_1 = time.strptime('08/01/2016','%d/%m/%Y')
>>> print date_1
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=8, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=8, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> date_2 = time.strptime('09/01/2016','%d/%m/%Y')
>>> print date_2
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=9, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> 
>>> date_1 < date_2
True
```

Dict with composite keys:

You need to have a binding keys for dict and later you are able to separate it.

Option 1:
use 2 layer dict, i.e.

```
date_cat_profit_dict[date_str] = dict()
date_cat_profit_dict[date_str][cat_str] = dict()
date_cat_profit_dict[date_str][cat_str]['name'] = name
date_cat_profit_dict[date_str][cat_str]['profit'] = profit
date_cat_profit_dict[date_str][cat_str]['date'] = date_1 #date object
```

Option 2:

```
date_cat_profit_dict[(date_str, cat_str)] = dict()
date_cat_profit_dict[(date_str, cat_str)]['name'] = name
date_cat_profit_dict[(date_str, cat_str)]['profit'] = profit
date_cat_profit_dict[(date_str, cat_str)]['date'] = date_1 #date object
```

Hope it helps you find the right way to solve your problem.

Comment: i don't know what u did here.